# Generic function with constraint vs passing a parameter of supertype in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm very new to the generics concept, so recently I stumbled upon some confusing situation.

I want to write a function which sends a file to a remote server. The file can be either an image or an audio. The difference for sending is going to be only how we work with file parameters (image width and height vs audio duration), and set up a type of a message. So it was only natural to write a general function for both use cases.

Let's say I have some class (in this case a sealed class for easy `when` checks) which has some inheritors.

```kotlin
sealed class MessageData

data class MessageAudioData(
    val duration: Float
) : MessageData()

data class MessageImageData(
    var width: Float,
    var height: Float
) : MessageData()
```

Initially I wanted to write a function like this:

```kotlin
fun <T : MessageData> sendFile(fileData: T) {
    ...
}
```

But with introduction of a sealed class, the `when` check doesn't work as it's supposed to. So I rewrote my function to be like this:

```kotlin
fun sendFile(fileData: MessageData) {
    ...
}
```

`when` check works, and I seem to have no problems with it.

But then I wondered if this is a correct way to go, and what the difference is. I have read about variance, and I think it would make a difference in a class (with `in` and `out`), but probably I'm missing something. Could anyone help me understand it better?

**EDIT**: I think I need to make myself a bit clearer since I've put too much attention to the sealed class.

I was mostly wondering about the usage and use cases of generic functions with constraints. Is it about working precisely with the type inside of a function? I mean, I can have `interface I`, and then have `class A` and `class B` implement this interface, and then write a function to work with them. It seems, I don't need to write a generic, I can just pass a parameter of type `I` and that would work with both `fun example(A())` and `fun example(B())`.

Comment: Second way is good to go, you can easily cast it to sub-type as well because type parameters don't have type-erasure. There is no need of using wild-cards here! even if you want it to cast then you'll require reifying & inlining it, it is great when code is smaller, but when its large it has no extra benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using your `when` statement to do *different* things depending on the type of the item passed to the function. Generics won't help with that at all.

Generics are mostly used for collection or container type classes, where you can put stuff in or take stuff out, and the compiler ensures that you're correctly interpreting the types going in or out. When it comes to functions, if your function isn't working with collections or generic container classes, it most likely has no reason to have a generic type.

Sealed classes sound like a suitable fit for your use case, where you have a finite number of types, they are simple data-type classes, and you want to handle each of them in a different way. Traditionally, handing an object to a function and having it check the type and cast and handle them differently is usually a code smell, because it can usually be solved more robustly with polymorphism (each object handles its own unique behavior). Sealed classes can resolve the risks and code-fragility that come from type-checking by enforcing all possibilities are handled.

Comment: Thank you! The part about generic type usage in functions is exactly what I was wondering about. What if it wasn't about a sealed class or ``when`` statement? And instead, say, I would have an interface which is implemented by a couple of classes, or a class with some inheritors, and I wanted to write a function to work with them. So, what would be the difference between writing a generic function and passing the type vs passing a parameter of a supertype? I mean, in both cases we don't know exactly what will be supplemented to the function, but we can restrain it with providing the supertype.

Comment: Suppose you have a function that modifies or creates a copy of an input parameter and returns it to you. If you pass a parameter of a supertype with no generic, then the returned object is only known to be the type of the supertype. If you used generics, it could return the exact same type you passed in without you needing to cast it. Generics let you get stuff out of containers, collections or functions without casting. If you're not working with containers or collections, or trying to return something whose type is related to whatever the input is, then generics are pointless complexity.